# From Pincode to State Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, api

I have this Java code:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class PincodeToState {

private String myState;

public void setPincode(String pin) {

    try {

        JSONObject jsonObj = JsonParser
                .getJSONfromURL("http://api.zippopotam.us/in/" + pin);

        JSONArray Results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("places");

        for (int i = 0; i < Results.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = Results.getJSONObject(i);

            myState = c.getString("state");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public String getState() {
    return myState;

}

}
```

Json code

Visit http://api.zippopotam.us/in/400031

Logcat Error

```
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443): Failed data was:
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):     <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML     2.0//EN">
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):     <html>
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):         <head>
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):             <title>Error: 405 Method Not Allowed</title>
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):             <style type="text/css">
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):               html {background-color: #eee; font-family: sans;}
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):               body {background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #ddd;
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):                     padding: 15px; margin: 15px;}
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):               pre {background-color: #eee; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px;}
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):             </style>
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):         </head>
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):         <body>
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):             <h1>Error: 405 Method Not    Allowed</h1>
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):             <p>Sorry, the requested URL    <tt>&#039;http://api.zippopotam.us/in/400072&#039;</tt>
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):                caused an error:</p>
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):             <pre>Method not allowed.</pre>
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):         </body>
07-06 20:41:11.052: E/log_tag(27443):     </html>
07-06 20:41:11.052: W/System.err(27443): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are issuing post request on the server.Please do get request on server.Then it will work.

**http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html**

Please visit above link.

I think this will solve the issue.

Comment: I tested the above solution on rest client. It's working if you issue get request to the web server.